# Google Actions: Testing Library complains about Firebase Terms

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm trying to implement tests for my Google Action with [Assistant Conversation Testing Library](https://github.com/actions-on-google/assistant-conversation-testing-nodejs#readme).

The problem is that the execution is complaining about: **"Firebase Terms of Service is not accepted"**. **I can't find any way to accept these terms** - neither in the [Actions Console](https://console.actions.google.com) or in the [Cloud Platform](https://console.cloud.google.com).

It was working ~two weeks ago and suddenly it stoped working with this error. As far as I know I haven't changed anything related. I also tried creating a new service_account.json, but this didn't help.

Error message/stacktrace:

```
Starting writePreview From Draft
Error: 9 FAILED_PRECONDITION: Firebase Terms of Service is not accepted. Navigate to your project's overview page on the Actions Console to accept the Terms of Service.
    at Object.callErrorFromStatus (test/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:26)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (test/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:244:52)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (test/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:334:141)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (test/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:297:181)
    at test/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:130:78
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11) {
  code: 9,
  details: "Firebase Terms of Service is not accepted. Navigate to your project's overview page on the Actions Console to accept the Terms of Service.",
  metadata: Metadata {
    internalRepr: Map(2) {
      'google.rpc.preconditionfailure-bin' => [Array],
      'grpc-status-details-bin' => [Array]
    },
    options: {}
  }
}
```

Source Code:

```
const { ActionsOnGoogleTestManager } = require('@assistant/conversation-testing');

async function openAction(projectId, invocationName) {
    const testManager = new ActionsOnGoogleTestManager({ projectId: projectId });
    testManager.setTestSurface('SMART_DISPLAY');
    testManager.setSuiteLocale("en-US")
    await testManager.writePreviewFromDraft();

    await testManager.sendQuery(`Talk to ${invocationName}`);
    testManager.assertText("Hello World")
    testManager.assertIntent('actions.intent.MAIN');
}
```

Comment: Can you open the Overview page for your project in the Actions Console?

Comment: @NickFelker Yes, I can open the Console. Everything looks good and I can't find any error.

Comment: Hey @Sebastian, did you find a solution to this. Just started running into the same issue.

Comment: @joedixon Still no solution. Maybe I try to create a complete new project and see if and/or when this occurs again.

Comment: @Sebastian did it work? Did you resolve this problem, or find something that will help with that?